# How can I cast generic properties?

Tags: c#, generics

How can I iterate through a collection of generic properties and cast them according to their respective types in a  given class ?

I have a global setting class as follows

```
    public class GlobalSettingModel<T> 
{
    public Guid SettingId { get; set; }
    public string SettingName { get; set; }
    public Type SettingType { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a SettingsService class that allows getting and setting of GlobalSettingModel properties thus  (I include one property here 'IsUserLogonByPassed ' for example purposes)

```
 public class SettingsService
{
    private readonly IGlobalSettingStore _settingStore;


    public SettingsService(IGlobalSettingStore settingStore)
    {
        _settingStore = settingStore;
        IsUserLogonByPassed = new GlobalSettingModel<bool>() 
            { SettingName = "IsUserLogonByPassed", SettingType = typeof(bool), Value = false };
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that determines if user logon is bypassed or not
    /// </summary>
    public GlobalSettingModel<bool> IsUserLogonByPassed { get; set; }



    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        var globalSettingProperties = GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(GlobalSettingModel<>));


        foreach (var property in globalSettingProperties)
        {
            var setting = property.GetValue(this, null) as GlobalSettingModel<>;
            if (setting != null) _settingStore.SaveSetting(setting.SettingName, setting.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the SaveSettings method at the line

```
var setting = property.GetValue(this, null) as GlobalSettingModel<>;
```

Obviously I get a "Type Expected" error when trying to compile this.  I am wondering how might I iterate through and cast all my GlobalSettingModel properties ?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Once you start using reflection (here it happens by populating `globalSettingProperties`) then you have to use reflection all the way.

There are alternatives such as making `setting` be of type `dynamic` that "feel" different, and this might in fact work for you here, but in principle the only thing you can do is to inspect the values at runtime; `dynamic` just offloads this work to the compiler and DLR.

Comment: Many thanks, I should add I am constrained to using .Net 3.5 so no access to dynamic.